# invalidate not redrawing view on api 25

Tags: android

I have a custom view that extends LinearLayout.
The view looks like progress bar with a little icon that moves on every click.
the updating method is :

```
public void setPointerOffset(int mPointerOffset) {
    this.mPointerOffset = mPointerOffset;
    updateSlider();
    invalidate();
    requestLayout();
}
private void updateSlider() {
    PercentFrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (PercentFrameLayout.LayoutParams) mPointer.getLayoutParams();
    PercentLayoutHelper.PercentLayoutInfo info = params.getPercentLayoutInfo();
    if (mPointerOffset < MIN_OFFSET)
        mPointerOffset = MIN_OFFSET;
    if (mPointerOffset > MAX_OFFSET)
        mPointerOffset = MAX_OFFSET;
    float percent = mPointerOffset * 0.01f;
    info.startMarginPercent = percent;
}
```

This method is fired up from onClickListener.
This is working great in low api like 17, but on the lest on (25) it doesn't working at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setting layout params to "mPointer" semms to fix it.

```
private void updateSlider() {
    PercentFrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (PercentFrameLayout.LayoutParams) mPointer.getLayoutParams();
    PercentLayoutHelper.PercentLayoutInfo info = params.getPercentLayoutInfo();
    if (mPointerOffset < MIN_OFFSET)
        mPointerOffset = MIN_OFFSET;
    if (mPointerOffset > MAX_OFFSET)
        mPointerOffset = MAX_OFFSET;
    float percent = mPointerOffset * 0.01f;
    info.startMarginPercent = percent;
    mPointer.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```